# some questions about sequential containers

Tags: iterator

In <<C++ primer>>(5th)9.3.6,the author said
"Iterators, pointers, and references to a vector or string are invalid if the
container was reallocated. If no reallocation happens, indirect references to
elements before the insertion remain valid; those to elements after the insertion
are invalid."
I con't understand why when no reallocation happens,those to elements after the insertion
are invalid.

When no reallocation happens,but why they are invalid? In my opinion,if nothing change in reallocation,the iterator won't change.How can I understand from memory principles .Does it affect data structures?